# How do I clean a JSON string with serialized formatting?

Tags: ruby, json

I tried to decode and parse the string that an API returns, however the syntax of the returned JSON object is weird.

I could just strip elements from the string, but was wondering what is the best way to clean up this JSON string and convert it to a Ruby hash?

```
"DataCallBack([
    {
        \"detail1\": \"result1\",
        \"detail2\": \"result2\",
        \"Attr1\": [
            {
                \"detail1\": \"result1\",
                \"detail2\": \"result2\",
            },
            {...}
        ]
        ],
        \"Attr2\": [
            {
                \"detail1\": \"result1\",
                \"detail2\": \"result2\",
            },
            {...}
        ]
    }
])"
```

Comment: This seems like just serialized [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) string.

Comment: That's not "weird", that's a regular JSON string with it's quotes escaped. It's possible it's just being rendered that way, and the backslashes don't actually exist within the string; have you tried `JSON.parse`?

Comment: It is a serialized JSONP string I think, but when I try `JSON.parse` or `decode` I get `JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at 'DataCallBack...`

Comment: You sure you can't get a version without the `DataCallBack` wrapper callback? JSONP is really _only_ designed to work with javascript.

Comment: Ah, @AlexWayne that makes sense. The developer has a widget with an `AJAX` call. At the moment, they don't have an API so he told me to just mimic the call. The `get` request needs the wrapper I think: `http://Clients.clientsite.com/Widgets/Quotes.ashx?callback=DataCallBack&partnerID=39&....`

Comment: Most APIs that support JSONP _also_ support raw JSON.  So if you are querying an API from your server, and not from AJAX, you typically don't pass the `callback` parameter and get raw JSON that you can directly parse. JSONP is simply a workaround that allows cross domain fetching of data in a browser.

Comment: @AlexWayne Awesome! Stripped out the `callback` param, and then I can parse the result with `JSON.parse` as it recognizes it as `JSON`! Thanks

Comment: @ElijahMurray w00t! I just added that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just request the data without the `?callback=DataCallBack` in the query string, and you will probably get raw JSON that you can directly parse.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to strip the JSON from a JSONP response:

```
jsonp = 'DataCallBack([
    {
        "detail1": "result1",
        "detail2": "result2",
        "Attr1": [
            {
                "detail1": "result1",
                "detail2": "result2"
            }
        ],
        "Attr2": [
            {
                "detail1": "result1",
                "detail2": "result2"
            }
        ]
    }
])'

require 'json'
JSON.parse(jsonp[/{.+}/m])
# => {"detail1"=>"result1",
#     "detail2"=>"result2",
#     "Attr1"=>[{"detail1"=>"result1", "detail2"=>"result2"}],
#     "Attr2"=>[{"detail1"=>"result1", "detail2"=>"result2"}]}
```

Your JSONP sample was mangled a bit, probably by trying to shorten it, so I cleaned it up to  be valid JSON.

The pattern `/{.+}/m` tells the regular expression engine to find everything contained by the outermost curly braces, which is the JSON. The `m` flag tell the engine to treat the whole string, containing line-ends, as a long string, which is necessary when using `.` because it won't normally match line-ends. At that point you'll have the JSON content, so then it's a simple matter of parsing it back into a Ruby object.